# Side panel components from Classic to Lightning

Tags: lightning, sidebar, salesforce-classic

Can items from Side Panel in Salesforce Classic be used in Lightning?
A company is thinking about switching to Lightning. Users use Side Panel for search, links and there is a Visualforce page (from installed package).
I don't see any possibility to add such kind of things in Lightning. Am I missing smth?

Answer (score 2):

The items that are in the side panel could potentially be inserted as an I-frame in a custom lightning page. However, this would best be done by creating a custom Lightning Component for them that's equivalent in functionality.

Comment: Can this Lightning Component be displayed on each screen as Side Panel in Classic?

Comment: Yes, if included in the markup. Lightning components are now supported in Classic. See the Visualforce in LIghtning Module in Trailhead.

Comment: Sorry, I formulate my question wrong. Can I put components in Lightning in the same way as in Side Panel in Salesforce Classic? I want a component in Lightning to be displayed on each screen or in as much screens as possible in Lightning.

Comment: Using the Lightning App Builder, you can easily add a component that would be displayed along the left column of every page it was added to in a 3 column page layout. Using custom code, you could do the same for any Lightning page, including specifying the relative width of the sidebar component compared to any others that used the custom page layout.